# How to make routing work with react, express and ionic?

Tags: reactjs, express, ionic-framework, react-router

I have a basic react setup with create-react-app.
Inside i have a server folder which contains an express node.js app.

I'm building the react app with npm start build

This creates a build folder which contains my front end files.

These files is served by the server.

**Server.js**

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cors = require("cors");
const session = require('express-session')
const path = require("path");

const {getIPAddress} = require("./Utils/utils");
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080

const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"../build")));
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(session({
    resave :false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie : {
        maxAge:(1000 * 60 * 100)
    }      
}));


app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,"../build","index.html"));
});

app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log(`App is running on ${getIPAddress()}:${port}`);
});
```

So far so good.

**(react) App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  setupIonicReact,
  IonTabs,
  IonTabBar,
  IonTabButton,
  IonIcon,
  IonLabel,
  IonRouterOutlet,
  IonFab,
  IonFabButton,
  IonFabList
} from '@ionic/react';
import { IonReactRouter } from '@ionic/react-router';

import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router';

import {
  planet,
  cut,
  library,
  settings,
  add
} from 'ionicons/icons';


import HotPage from './pages/HotPage';
import TrendingPage from './pages/TrendingPage';
import FreshPage from './pages/FreshPage';
import SettingsPage from './pages/SettingsPage';

import '@ionic/react/css/core.css';
/* Basic CSS for apps built with Ionic */
import '@ionic/react/css/normalize.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/structure.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/typography.css';

/* Optional CSS utils that can be commented out */
import '@ionic/react/css/padding.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/float-elements.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/text-alignment.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/text-transformation.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/flex-utils.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/display.css';

setupIonicReact();

function App() {
  return (
    <IonReactRouter>
      <IonTabs>
        <IonRouterOutlet>
          <Redirect exact path="/" to="/" />
          <Route path="/" render={() => <HotPage />} exact={true} />
          <Route path="/trending" render={() => <TrendingPage />} exact={true} />
          <Route path="/fresh" render={() => <FreshPage />} exact={true} />
          <Route path="/settings" render={() => <SettingsPage />} exact={true} />
        </IonRouterOutlet>

        <IonTabBar slot="bottom">
          <IonTabButton tab="hot" href="/">
            <IonIcon icon={planet} />
            <IonLabel>Hot</IonLabel>
          </IonTabButton>

          <IonTabButton tab="trending" href="/trending">
            <IonIcon icon={cut} />
            <IonLabel>Trending</IonLabel>
          </IonTabButton>

          <IonTabButton tab="fresh" href="/fresh">
            <IonIcon icon={library} />
            <IonLabel>Fresh</IonLabel>
          </IonTabButton>

          <IonTabButton tab="settings" href="/settings">
            <IonIcon icon={settings} />
            <IonLabel>Settings</IonLabel>
          </IonTabButton>
        </IonTabBar>
      </IonTabs>

    </IonReactRouter>
  );
}
export default App;
```

This creates a bottom tab bar.

When the user clicks on one of the tab buttons, the ionic router kicks in and takes care of the client side routing. This is working, it is rendering the other pages fine.

But if the user goes to one of the pages and refreshes the page, the server gives me an error since this route does not exists. Same if i send a link to somebody on my local network with the route.

For example. Base url is localhost:8080/ if i go to the Trending page the url will be localhost:8080/trending. From now on, if i refresh the page it wants to go to the /trending route but express don't know about this route.

Can i avoid this or is there any workaround?

Should i create every route on the server side and somehow redirect or rewrite the client url so the router act on it?

If i do this in my server

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,"../build","index.html"));
});
```

Then every route will go to the home page but without url change. This is not ideal ( does not create errors ) because if i want to link my trending page to someone, i can't tell him to go to the trending page after clicked the link which supposed to take him to the trending page.

Answer (score 0):

So i managed to make it work.

I have imported `createBrowserHistory` and applied it to my react router component.
This way the router will check the history and render the page i want on load.

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

function App() {
  const history = createBrowserHistory();
  return (
    <IonReactRouter history={history}>
       // rest of the tabs...
    </IonReactRouter>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: You'll probably want to move `const history = createBrowserHistory();` *outside* the `App` component code so you aren't creating a new `history` object reference any time `App` renders for any reason.

Comment: It does not compile for some reason